# How to show text lookup for a value with ActiveAdmin show on an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a `User` model that `has_one subscription_type`. I'm trying to show one of the fields from `subscription_type`, but its value is an integer (0, 1) and I want to show the corresponding text (free, premium).

Currently:

```ruby
  show do |user|
    default_main_content
    panel 'subscription' do
      attributes_table_for user.subscription_type do
        row :subscription_type
      end
    end
  end
```

This works ok, but it shows the integer value of `:subscription_type` here.

I have a hash on the `SubscriptionType` model that can be used to look up the key from the value and to humanize it:

```ruby
SubscriptionType::TYPES.key(1).to_s
=> "premium"
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to actually use that lookup in the row definition here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass `SubscriptionType::TYPES.key(subscription_type).to_s` as block to row

```
  show do |user|
    default_main_content
    panel 'subscription' do
      attributes_table_for user.subscription_type do
        row :subscription_type do
          SubscriptionType::TYPES.key(user.subscription_type).to_s
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is almost exactly right -- unfortunately (and annoyingly) the SubscriptionType model has a SubscriptionType attribute, so it actually ends up being user.subscription_type.subscription_type -- but there's no way you would've known that from what I wrote. Thanks so much!!!!